# SQL Return Row ID if a field matches my search term grouped by my Row ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm sorry if the title is confusing, it is better explained in an example.

I have a table of data like this:

```
1    ProductA    'Cheesy'
2    ProductA    'Creamy'
3    ProductA    'Juicy'
4    ProductB    'Buttery'
5    ProductB    'Clean'
6    ProductC    'Bitter'
```

I want to past a search term, for example, 'Cheesy' and 'Juicy'. This should return:

```
ProductA
```

...because ProductA matches with id 1 and 3.

But if I search for 'Cheesy' and 'Bitter', this should return no records as ProductA may have 'Cheesy' but it does not contain a record for 'Bitter'.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using `INTERSECT` in your query?

Comment: @user92546: Good point, why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @Andomar - Addressed your concern below.  Sometimes users are willing to provide some notion of what they have attempted.  Sometimes a nudge in a productive direction suffices.  Other times they just want the bloody answer NOW!  So it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

```
declare @Products as Table ( ProductId Int Identity, Product VarChar(16), Property VarChar(16) )
insert into @Products ( Product, Property ) values
  ( 'ProductA', 'Cheesy' ), ( 'ProductA', 'Creamy' ), ( 'ProductA', 'Juicy' ),
  ( 'ProductB', 'Buttery' ), ( 'ProductB', 'Clean' ),
  ( 'ProductC', 'Bitter' )

select Product
  from @Products
  where Property = 'Cheesy'
intersect
select Product
  from @Products
  where Property = 'Juicy'
```

**EDIT:** Additional example:

```
-- To retrieve all data for the matching product(s):    
select *
  from @Products
  where Product in (
    select Product
      from @Products
      where Property = 'Cheesy'
    intersect
    select Product
      from @Products
      where Property = 'Juicy' )
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. I have done the following:

SELECT     Product
FROM         Product
WHERE     (Property = 'Cheesy')
INTERSECT
SELECT     Product
FROM         Product
WHERE     (Property = 'Juicy')

Can you tell me why, when I instead do a "SELECT *", this does not work?

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055(v=sql.105).aspx) `INTERSECT` implies `DISTINCT` values.  When you select additional columns, the values are different and the intersection is empty.  I'll edit my answer to provide another example.

Answer (score 1):

```
select product from products 
where property = 'Cheesy' -- property 1
or 
property = 'Juicy' -- property 2
group by product
having count(*) >= 2 -- number of properties
```

Something along these lines could work too, I think.